# Can I enter Oman twice in a short period of time, using a visa-on-arrival?

Tags: visas-on-arrival, repeat-visits, oman

As a German national coming to Oman for tourist purposes I am eligible for Visa On Arrival of the 26A/B Tourist Visit Visa (A=10, B=30 days), which states:

> Entry: Visa can be used for a single entry to Oman.

I will enter through MCT airport, stay in Oman for 5 days, then make a day-trip by car to Dubai. After the day trip to Dubai I will return to Oman for another 14 days and will leave the Arab Peninsula and head home after 20 days total.

Do I understand correctly that I have to get: a 26A when arriving through MCT, an exit stamp at Hatta border crossing when heading for Dubai, and a 26B at Hatta the next day when returning from UAE?

Will the 26B be granted or will I run into trouble as the officer expects a visa run?

Comment: We can't predict the questions the officer will ask, if any. His suspicions might be aroused and interrogate you about visa runs, or he may just not care. It can't really be answered by anyone other than the officer :(